# How can I publish my package to hex when my dependencies are not there?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My package depends on packages that are currently only on `github`. I tried to pull the packages down to my own vendor folder so my `dependencies` part looks like this:

```
 defp deps(:prod) do
    [
     {:ex_doc, "~> 0.16.2"},
     {:finder, path: "vendor/Finder" },
     {:erlware_commons, "~> 1.0"},
     {:pattern_tap, path: "vendor/elixir-pattern-tap"},
     {:temp, "~> 0.2"},
    ]
  end
```

When I try running `mix hex.publish` I get this error:

> ** (Mix) Stopping package build due to errors. Dependencies excluded from the package (only Hex packages can be dependencies): finder,
>   pattern_tap

Is there a work around for this, something that tells hex the packages are locally managed so it won't be a problem ?

Comment: You'll have to publish those as separate packages on hex as far as I know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38949727/1650580

Comment: Based on an earlier comment can one do this: "You need to include the stuff you're depending on from github. That is, get the source and build and then remove the github dependency. Just freeze the code on the version you pull from github." ?

Comment: Did you try the [git:](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html#module-git-options-git) option for your dependencies?

Comment: Same error @guitarman

Comment: Like the error says. You can only have other packages on hex as dependencies in order to put something on hex.

Comment: Yeah, just that I am on an impasse now. Those packages that I use don't belong to me so I cannot publish on hex.pm. I considered pulling those packages locally into my own source code and taking them off `mix.exs` but there are not many examples on how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publish a package to hex with a dependency from github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949604/how-to-publish-a-package-to-hex-with-a-dependency-from-github)